# Need some help on some Java homework creating circles

Tags: java, geometry

First of all, here is the requirements for my assignment:

Create a Circle class that contains:

> - a private double data field named radius.
> - a public constructor that creates a circle with a specified radius.
> - a public method `getRadius()` that returns the radius of this circle.
> - a public `compareCircle(Circle c)` method that returns true if the specified circle's radius is the same and the radius of this circle.
> - a public `setRadiusTheSame(Circle c)` method that changes this circle's radius to be the same as the specified circle's radius.

Write a test program that creates two circles of radii 18 and 5.  Prints out the radius for each circle, checks and prints if the two circles are equal, and then calls the compareCircle(Circle c) method and prints out the result.  Next call the setRadiusTheSame(Circle c) method.  Then print out everything again!

I need help writing the `compareCircle(Circle c)` method and the `setRadiusTheSame(Circle c)` method. Everything else compiles and works.

Here is my code so far for my Circle program:

```
public class Circle {           

   private double radius;

   public Circle() {
      radius = 18;
   }

   public Circle(double r) {
      radius = r;

   }

   public double getRadius() {
     return radius; 
   } 
}
```

And here is my TestCircle program so far:

```
public class TestCircle {   
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Circle c1 = new Circle();

      System.out.println("The circle has radius of " 
         + c1.getRadius());

      Circle c2 = new Circle(5);

      System.out.println("The circle has radius of " 
         + c2.getRadius());
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The requirement "public compareCircle(Circle c) method that returns true" virtually writes the method signature for you. What Java type supports the value 'true'? 
 public TypeThatReturnsTrueOrFalse compareCircle(Circle circle) { // stuff

Substitute the correct type for 'TypeThatReturnsTrueOrFalse'.

For the body, consider the requirement "if the specified circle's radius is the same and [sic] the radius of this circle" - how do you get at the "specified circle's radius"?   circle.getRadius()

and for this circle: inside the code just 'getRadius()'.

So: 'if (circle.getRadius() == getRadius()) { ... return something ...}'

The requirement says to "return true" for that condition so that should give you a hint about 'something'. But wait! The condition 'circle.getRadius() == getRadius()' already evaluates to either 'true' or 'false', so you can return that expression directly. Doing an 'if (somethingTrueOrFalse) { return true; } else { return false; }' is silly. Just 'return somethingTrueOrFalse;'

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what problem you are having, so people are mad that you are treating SO as a code writing service. Bad form.

- Add `compareCircle(Circle c)` to `Circle` and compare the radii, e.g., `return this.radius == c.getRadius();`
- add `setRadiusTheSame(Circle c)` to `Circle` and set the radius to the new radius, e.g., `this.radius = c.getRadius();`
- Finally: Write a test program that creates two circles of radii 18 and 5. Prints out the radius for each circle, checks and prints if the two circles are equal, and then calls the compareCircle(Circle c) method and prints out the result. Next call the setRadiusTheSame(Circle c) method. Then print out everything again!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a boolean method to compare 2 circle

```
public boolean isEqual(Circle c1, Circle c2)
{
   boolean status = true;
   if(c1.getRadius() != c2.getRadius())
       status = false

   return status;
}
```